# Why isn’t “community-wiki” showing up in tag search?

Tags: support, tags, community-wiki

I see on Stack Exchange Linguistics that I could post an answer and tick the box “make community wiki”.

But if I search “community-wiki” in the tag search in lefthand-side menu, there is no result for any such tag; whereas there are for Meta Stack Exchange.

Why does it seem that some sites don’t tag their wikis so you can’t search for them?

Comment: Better to ask in [meta.linguistics.se]

Comment: @Rubén why? wanting to find wiki posts is universal.

Comment: Just seems odd that the OP asked here, rather than on [meta.linguistics.se] or (because as you mention it's a feature across all the sites) [meta.se], @RobertLongson .

Comment: @RobertLongson The question looks to me to be "too broad" and a bit odd that a "foreign site" was mentioned. More details in my [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421018/1595451)

Answer (score 7):

Community-wiki status isn't a tag, it's more a state posts have, like deleted or closed etc.

If you click on the search field some help drops down and on the bottom right is a [Search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) button. If you click on that you'll get a page that tells you about this search term amongst many others...

> wiki: yes/true/1 returns only [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) posts; no/false/0 returns only non-community wiki posts.

The [community-wiki](/questions/tagged/community-wiki) tag on this meta is to discuss the concept of community wiki posts. Such posts aren't themselves community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Meta sites, like this have [community-wiki](/questions/tagged/community-wiki) tags for questions about this feature, not for making easier to search for actual community wikis.

Having a tag to search for community wikis on main sites might not make sense as there is a boolean search operator for that. From the article about Advanced Search

> `wiki:` yes/true/1 returns only [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) posts; no/false/0 returns only non-community wiki posts.

---

From the question

> Why does it seem that some sites don’t tag their wikis so you can’t search for them?

It sounds odd to me that this question was posted in Meta Stack Overflow, by one side because mentions a sister site rather the corresponding main site.

If you are looking for help with the technical part of community wikis, as it's a common feature for all sites, even the question mentions a "foreign site" it might be fine to ask about that on any meta, but it depends on each of them how the receive those questions.

If you are looking for help about how features are used across all the Stack Exchange network, that might require to do a lot of research as each community has certain autonomy to decide how the technical features will be used and because not every site might have "ambassadors" on Meta SE.

One example of a site making a use of a feature a bit differently than others is [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com). They have some tags use with a tag icon "reserved" for sponsored tags to draw special attention to them without having a sponsor (ref. [What is the logo on the Prior Art Request tag?](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/q/353)). This might required to coordinate with with the community manager but there are several elements that could be customized by the mods, several things that might be decided by the community without the participation of the community manager and others just are practices that spontaneously emerged.

Also it might be possible that each community use different names for tags about the same topic, i.e. on Meta SE the tag for tag warnings it [`tag-warnings`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-warnings) but here on Meta SO the tag for the same topic is [`tag-tips`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-tips).